# 6-j symbols and hypergeometric series

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

What’s the correct formula for $_{4}F_{3}(a,b,c,d;e,f,g;1)$ where $a+b+c+d-e-f-g=-1$?

The Wolfram Alpha formula involves $6j$ symbols and makes no sense for some specific cases.  For example, $_{4}F_{3}(5/4,1/4,1/4,1/4; 1,1,1; 1)$ is a finite number, but the $6j$ symbol formula gives zero.

Comment: This is link to the formula I’m having issue with: https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric4F3/03/02/02/

Comment: In the $6j$ formula from your link, one divides by $\Gamma(1-b_1)$, where $b_1=1$. It might be because of this Mathematica gives zero.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple formula for the balanced ${}_4F_3$. It is only directly related to $6j$-symbols when it terminates (is a finite sum) and that is not the case for your parameters.